# How to make a background image not cover labels in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, background

I am making a simple maths game but my background is covering the labels

how do I make it so the background image still resizes to the screen but is under the labels instead?

this is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# INITIALIZE TKINTER
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Test De Multiplications')
#root.iconbitmap('')
root.geometry('600x400')


# DEFINE FONTS
labelfont = font.Font(family='Comic Sans MS', weight='bold', size='30')
normalfont = font.Font(family='Arial', size='20')
subtitle = font.Font(family='Calibri', weight='bold', size='25')

# RAISING FRAMES (Swithching windows)
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')


title = Label(f1, text="TEST DE MULTIPLICATIONS", font=labelfont)
title.pack(side= TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

start = Button(f1, text='Commencer', font=normalfont, background='darkred', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2))
start.pack(side= TOP, expand= True)

playtitle = Label(f2, text='QUESTION:', font=normalfont ).pack()

raise_frame(f1)

class bg(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)



        self.image = Image.open("bg.ppm")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()


        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)



e = bg(root)
e.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)



root.mainloop()
```

I'm using multiple frames for the window switching so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it? I still want to be able to change windows like this, because it works well.

Comment: You need to create `bg` before creating other widgets. Or call `e.lower()`.

Comment: now it sorta works, but the buttons and text are showing up on top of it instead of on it

Comment: What do you mean by *"the buttons and text are showing up on top of it instead of on it"*.  The button and the text are in another frame and this frame overlaps the frame containing the image.  So what do you expect actually?

Comment: As far as I know its hard to put a button on a background and not have it overlapped. You cant just build it in the background image but you also cant make the button transparent. I can only think of a somewhat tricky workaround solution. You could check what part of the image would be displayed on the button. Then you just take that smaller picture and put it on the button.